# Is it okay to specify different version of chromedriver in the headers and have different chromedriver.exe version?

Tags: python, google-chrome, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

Google Chrome installed on my computer is 103.0.5060.53 version. But in my code I've specified 91.0.4472.114 version. And chromedriver.exe I'm using is 102.0.5005.

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\NCF_GoogleDrive\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get(paper_url)
doc=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
```

I have couple of questions:

1. Is that a problem? What problems can that cause?
2. Does that somehow change the html code of the webpage? Would I get different content in 'doc' variable depending on the versions?
3. Does that create any problems for webscraping? Would I find the information I want to scrape under different tags/classes/ids or whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a custom User Agent header with a browser version that is different than your chromedriver is not a problem neither for the website nor for the script to some extent.

If you use a browser version that is **very** old and does not support certain features used by the website you are requesting, it may return a slightly different HTML format than what you see with your browser. This does not happen with all websites but some of them. E.g. google:

(Left is a **very** old version, right is a recent / current version)

[image: Google HTML page with different header user-agents]

Tags or HTML format in general may differ with different versions (but usually similar for all recent versions), so you may face issues with web scraping. However, it is not a frequent issue based on my experience.